# how to remove the small black screen

Tags: macos

Hi i think this is the not best place to ask this question, and i don't knoe where to ask these type of questions....

but can anyone tell me that how to remove that small
black screen

[image]

it just gives status of what i am currently doing...

i don't know what is this but it irritating me....

is it a **virus**?

i am unable to remove it.from my mac ...

Comment: Couldn't you migrate it to the Apple-related SE site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off "Voiceover" in the System Preferences, under "Universal Access" (or press `Command-F5`).

Comment: Your question got closed... NP.

Comment: no problem man ...i got answer....